# .htaccess rewrite conditions for https:// pre tag subdomains

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

I need some extra code in my `.htaccess` file that configures this HTTP request for HTTPS too!

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/sponsor/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

Options +FollowSymlinks
</ifmodule>
```

My problem: now it gets the `/sponsor` tag only if I type the example with `http:`

GOOD:

- This is working: `http://subdomain.example.com` results in `http://subdomain.example.com/sponsor/subdomain`.

BAD:

- This isn't working: `https://subdomain.example.com` results in `https://subdomain.example.com/`.

I need a `.htaccess` rewrite, that automatically puts the `/sponsor` TAG into the HTTPS URLs too.

**UPDATE:** Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com [OR,NC]
RewriteCond https://%{HTTPS_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/sponsor/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: The code you posted is not doing this. Please post your entire `.htaccess` file. The code you posted would result in a "redirect loop" - so there would seem to be _something else_ going on here? It also does not differentiate between HTTP and HTTPS, so again, _something else_ is going on here if you are seeing a different response. The code you posted (even if it did "work") would not result in the "GOOD" redirect you've stated - so, yet again, _something else_ is going on here.

Comment: Here is more for you:

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>



Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com [OR,NC]
RewriteCond https://%{HTTPS_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/sponsor/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]



Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Comment: I just need the /sponsor/ current subdomain for every TYPED URL in the browser. For http:// and for https:// url's too.

Comment: I've edited your question and added your code dump. Apart from "looking a mess", when you post unformatted code it is likely that certain characters get omitted from display, particularly in regex - so please check my edit for any copy/paste errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com [OR,NC]
> RewriteCond https://%{HTTPS_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/sponsor/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
> ```

Slightly different to the directives you posted initially, however, the second condition will never match, so the result is the same.

But as stated in my comment, this will result in a "redirect loop" and could not possibly result in either of the redirect responses you state in the question ("good" or "bad"). So, either you are seeing a cached response or `.htaccess` (or mod_rewrite) is not enabled and WordPress itself is performing this redirect?! (Although presumably, you do have WordPress "pretty" URLs enabled?)

Note that your `RewriteRule` *substitution* string is duplicating the URL-path, both at the front of the URL-path (`%{REQUEST_URI}`) and at the end (with the `$1` backreference) - so this would also break on anything other than the document root (which is all you seem to be testing in your question).

Also, you should never add your own directives to the WordPress code block - otherwise WordPress will "try" to overwrite your code when it updates.

You should add your own directives *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section.

To perform the required redirect you would need something like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule !^sponsor/ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/sponsor/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

**UPDATE:** Remove the trailing `$` on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. ie. What was `!^sponsor/$` should be `!^sponsor/` (as above).

Note that the above will also catch the `www` subdomain, if that is enabled. If you only have the one domain (ie. `example.com`) then you can simplify the condition to read:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.
```

In summary, with all code in place:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.
RewriteRule !^sponsor/ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/sponsor/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

There is no need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive.

Make sure you clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: Hi MrWhite,

I am very.very thank you this suggestion. Thanks for the tipps too. It seems very close to my success. Now the code works with http:// and with https:// too, but the url gives back a continuosly /sponsor/example/sponsor/example/sponsor/example TAG.

When i open HTTP http://subdomain.example.com or HTTPS https://subdomain.example.com i get http://subdomain.example.com/sponsor/example/sponsor/example/sponsor/example/sponsor/example

I think missing some closing tag.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, there was an error in the regex.... Remove the trailing `$` on the `RewriteRule` _pattern_. ie. What was `!^sponsor/$` should be `!^sponsor/` - I've updated my answer.

Comment: 1 last question: Can we remove the default adding "index.php" from the end of the URL?

Comment: That's a very different question. It's not clear why "index.php" would be added in the first place (unless you don't have WordPress "pretty" permalinks enabled)? It's not something that these directives are doing.

Comment: Yes, the pretty permalinks are enabled. Now all the URL's get at the end the index.php tag. It would be better for me this way simple: https://subdomain.example.com/sponsor/example/

Comment: What happens if you request `https://subdomain.example.com/sponsor/subdomain` directly?